# How to deserialize JSON to List?

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-mvc, serialization

I have a serialized JSON string `serializedClaims` -

```
var claims = new List<Claim>();

claims.Add(new Claim("MakerId", "939393", ClaimValueTypes.String));
claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.DateOfBirth, "1956-03-08", ClaimValueTypes.Date));

var serializedClaims = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(claims);
```

Now I want to deserialize `serializedClaims` back to a `List<Claim>`.

How to do that?

Comment: Does `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Claim>>(serializedClaims);` not work?

Comment: No it does not , errors out "Unable to find a constructor for System.Security.Claims.Claim"

Comment: @GilliVilla You have to add Constructor to your `Claim` class.

Comment: Specifically, you have to add a default constructor, so `public Claim() {...}`. This is because under the covers, `JsonConvert` is iterating over the JSON objects in `serializedClaims`, and for each, creating a new `Claim` using the default constructor, and using reflection to populate properties of that object using similarly named entries in the JSON object.

Answer (score 1):

You can do by specified the `List<Claim>` type in conversion

```
var dserializedClaims = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Claim>>(serializedClaims);
```

Comment: It should be `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Claim>>(...`.

Comment: Now it's just like Nihal Rp's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
List<Claim> deserializedClaims = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Claim>>(serializedClaims);
```

Comment: No. Errors out.

Answer (score 0):

You can DeserializeObject using JsonConvert and you also specified its settings for format of json data.like

```
      var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None
        };
       List<Claim> claims =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Claim>>(serializedClaims, settings);
```

using this setting you can ignore the null value and provide date parse handling